# UPDATE column from one table to another

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012-express

I need to update a column in a table to the latest date/time combination from another table.  How can I get the latest date/time combination from the one table and then update a column with that date in another table?

The two tables I am using are called `dbo.DD` and `dbo.PurchaseOrders`.  The JOIN between the two tables are `dbo.DueDate.XDORD = dbo.PurchaseOrders.PBPO AND dbo.DueDate.XDLINE = dbo.PurchaseOrders.PBSEQ`.  The columns from dbo.DueDate that I need the latest date/time from are `dbo.DueDate.XDCCTD and dbo.DueDate.XDCCTT`.

I need to set `dbo.PurchaseOrders.PBDUE = dbo.DueDate.XDCURDT`.I can't use an ORDER BY statement in the UPDATE statement, so I'm not sure how to do this.  I know row_number sometimes works in these situations, but I'm unsure of how to implement.

Comment: Who names your tables and columns? Ugh.

Comment: LOL.  I know Aaron, I'm sorry but I do not have control over the naming conventions.  They do have "meaning" to me sometimes.

Comment: Kind of like my license plate has meaning to me sometimes - but not to anyone else, really, ever.

Comment: I just wanted to show the working code.  That code does work for me now.

Comment: I've added it to the answer, a more relevant spot for it. Code samples in the question should be what you've tried (or schema / sample data setup), accompanied with why what you tried didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general pattern is:

```
;WITH s AS 
(
  SELECT  
   key, -- may be multiple columns
   date_col, 
   rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER  
   (
     PARTITION BY key -- again, may be multiple columns
     ORDER BY date_col DESC
   )
  FROM dbo.SourceTable
)
UPDATE d 
  SET d.date_col = s.date_col
  FROM dbo.DestinationTable AS d
  INNER JOIN s 
  ON d.key = s.key -- one more time, may need multiple columns here
WHERE s.rn = 1;
```

I didn't try to map your table names and columns because (a) I didn't get from your word problem which table was the source and which was the destination and (b) those column names look like alphabet soup and I would have screwed them up anyway.

Did seem though that the OP got this specific code working:

```
;WITH s AS 
    (
      SELECT  
       XDORD, XDLINE,
       XDCURDT,
       rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER  
       (
         PARTITION BY XDORD, XDLINE
         ORDER BY XDCCTD DESC, XDCCTT desc
       )
      FROM dbo.DueDate
    )
    UPDATE d 
      SET d.PBDUE = s.XDCURDT
      FROM dbo.PurchaseOrders AS d
      INNER JOIN s 
      ON d.PBPO = s.XDORD AND d.PBSEQ = s.XDLINE
    WHERE s.rn = 1;
```